# what is the best way to create a class members in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

What is the Best Way To Define Object Memeber and Please Explain Why

1 : 1st Way

```
var Obj = {
           M1 : 1,
           M2 : 2    
}
```

Using it like

```
 Obj.M1
```

2 :2nd Way

```
var Obj = function(){
 if (!(this instanceof Obj ))
            return new Obj ();
}
Obj.prototype.M1 =1 ;
Obj.prototype.M2 =2 ;
```

Using it Like

```
Obj().M1;
```

i mean with all that is using prototype better than defining the whole members with in these {} ?

Comment: since 1st way you created an object literal, these are technically **instance variables**, not **member variables**, i believe.. (javascript as a prototypical language doesn't need classes to define object instances - see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2800964/benefits-of-prototypal-inheritance-over-classical)

Comment: I Found Some Answers There 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4736910/javascript-when-to-use-prototypes

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12180790/defining-methods-via-prototype-vs-using-this-in-the-constructor-really-a-perfo

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/310870/use-of-prototype-vs-this-in-javascript

Answer (score 4):

That dependes whether you want to create multiple instances of `Obj` or just one.
Aspects from class-based object oriented languages like inheritance are only possible when you use the second way (it's not real inheritance as you know it from class-based OO languages, but it's similar).
Generally you can compare the first way with a static class in class-based OO programming languages in case you are more familiar with them.

Comment: javascript is object-oriented, it's just a prototypical instead of classical programming language (doesn't use classes, but prototypes).