# What is the use of prototype in Node js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, prototype

Im new to Node js language In most of the Node js sample app all are using prototype.Then i came to know using prototype we can add the methods and properties into an object.Still i'm not clear about what is the use of prototype.Can anyone explain me.

Comment: This may be helpful: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Introduction_to_Object-Oriented_JavaScript

Comment: Prototyping is a characteristic of Javascript, the language `node.js` is based on. I suggest you to read some resource about Javascript and prototyping. For example [the 8th chapter of Eloquent Javascript](http://eloquentjavascript.net/chapter8.html).

Comment: possible duplicate of [How does JavaScript .prototype work?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/572897/how-does-javascript-prototype-work) or [Javascript when to use prototypes](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4736910/1048572) - there is nothing specific about Node.js!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short, `prototype` is used to build the interface (and implementation) of your custom-build objects in JavaScript.

As said Blender in the comment, it's how you do real OOP in JavaScript.

Answer (score 1):

Using a prototype will also mean that you can define a method in one place (low memory footprint). Not defining a method via a prototype means that the method is defined for each instance of said object (high memory footprint).