# overriding prototype property or function

Tags: javascript, constructor, overriding, prototype

```
function Ninja(){
  this.swingSword = function(){
    return true;
  };
}

// Should return false, but will be overridden
Ninja.prototype.swingSword = function(){
  return false;
};

var ninja = new Ninja();
log( ninja.swingSword(), "Calling the instance method, not the prototype method." );
```

now log showing me true. which means swingSword that were defined in Ninja.prototype has overridden so how can i override the constructor function or property.??
i know that preference is given to constructor variable then why need to define a function or property inside prototype??

Comment: Own properties have preference, that's how the prototype chain works. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Inheritance_and_the_prototype_chain

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason to define a function on the prototype is so that it is shared between all instances. This will save you some memory rather than each instance having its own copy of a function defined in the constructor.

Some other references you might be interested in:

[Javascript when to use prototypes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4736910/javascript-when-to-use-prototypes)

http://javascript.crockford.com/inheritance.html

Comment: the only adventage is to save memoray oki but how can i manipulate the constructor values or func

Comment: To change an instance variable value that you set in the constructor, you can reference it using `this`. So, if you had set something like `this.shouldSwingSword = true;` in the constructor, you could set `this.shouldSwingSword = false;` in your function. Then, you do checks like `if ninja.shouldSwingSword`. You should probably not need to put functions inside the constructor, though. Those should typically go on the prototype or just the class object itself (i.e., a static method)

Comment: You could also basically just change the value directly outside of any function: `ninja.shouldSwingSword = false;`. Is this what you are asking?

Answer (score 1):

This is by design. Do not set the value in the constructor if you want it to return false.

You can also make a setter method:

```
function Ninja() {
    var swordState = true;
    this.swingSword = function () {
        return swordState;
    };
    this.setSword = function (b) {
        swordState = b;
    };
}

// Should return false, but will be overridden
Ninja.prototype.swingSword = function () {
    return false;
};

var ninja = new Ninja();
console.log(ninja.swingSword(), "Calling the instance method, not the prototype method.");
ninja.setSword(false);
console.log(ninja.swingSword()); // returns false
```

Answer (score -1):

A simple example of `Object.create`:

```js
const obj = {
    hello: function() { return this.name },
  name: "karl"
}

const bla = Object.create(obj);
const wha = Object.create(obj);

console.log(obj.hello()); // karl
console.log(bla.hello()); // karl
console.log(wha.hello()); // karl

wha.name = "derp"

console.log(obj.hello()); // karl
console.log(bla.hello()); // karl
console.log(wha.hello()); // derp

obj.name = "hihi"

console.log(obj.hello()); // hihi
console.log(bla.hello()); // hihi
console.log(wha.hello()); // derp
```